# How can I add space between this shortcode and Contact us

Tags: wordpress

How can I add space between shortcode and Contact us page in the header of the theme. I was able to add the shortcode successfully. Now I am unable to add the gap between shortcode and contact us.

[image]

Below I have attached the code to this header file. After
     `do_action( 'ciyashop_header_nav_content' );`

I have added `echo do_shortcode('[searchandfilter id="2819"]');` thats my shortcode.

```
<?php do_action( 'ciyashop_before_header_nav' );?> 

<div class="<?php ciyashop_header_nav_classes('header-nav');?>">
<div class="header-nav-wrapper">

    <?php
    /**
     * Functions hooked into ciyashop_before_header_nav_content action
     *
     * @hooked ciyashop_before_header_nav_content_wrapper_start  - 10
     */


    do_action( 'ciyashop_before_header_nav_content' );

    /**
     * Functions hooked into ciyashop_header_nav_content action
     *
     * @hooked ciyashop_category_menu                 - 10
     * @hooked ciyashop_catmenu_primenu_separator     - 15
     * @hooked ciyashop_primary_menu                  - 20
     */
    do_action( 'ciyashop_header_nav_content' );  

/*  echo do_shortcode('[searchandfilter id="2819"]'); */ My Shortcode


    /**
     * Functions hooked into ciyashop_after_header_nav_content action
     *
     * @hooked ciyashop_after_header_nav_content_wrapper_end  - 10
     */
    do_action( 'ciyashop_after_header_nav_content' );


    ?>




</div>
```

Comment: Why not add padding with CSS?

Comment: I tried but I am getting some 'missing ?>' issues every time, I do it

Comment: please share me the site url

Comment: i cannot see the filter in your header